# Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

While im building react route for my react app The Error show up

> Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Below is my code

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      //Make App Running within Browser Router//
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <div className="navbar">
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/chat' component={Chat} />
          <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

      <div className="main-container"> **==> This is when problem show**
        <Searchapp />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196817/adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You must encapsulate the JSX with a parent node. You can make use of a div element or if you don't want to add an extra element in the DOM, you can make use of React Fragment <>

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <>
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <div className="navbar">
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/chat' component={Chat} />
          <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

      <div className="main-container"> **==> This is when problem show**
        <Searchapp />
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not allowed to assign multiple JSX elements to a single variable, not valid JavaScript syntax.

You are trying to place some sibling elements next to each other but you have to have a single outside tag, but what if adding an extra `<div>` tag throws off your styling?

So what the previous answer offered is called `React.Fragment` which is a JSX looking element that will allow you to assign multiple elements to a single variable but when rendered to a screen it will not produce any visible element to the DOM.

It would look something like this:

```
const ObjectDelete = () => {
  const actions = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button className="ui button negative">Delete</button>
      <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

which is basically the long form which can be shortened like so:

```
const ObjectDelete = () => {
  const actions = (
    <>
      <button className="ui button negative">Delete</button>
      <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
    </>
  );
```

Or if it's more helpful for you since you presented a class component:

```
class ObjectDelete extends React.Component {
  renderActions() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="ui button negative">Delete</button>
        <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Make note that at this point the JSX with `<React.Fragment>` is enclosed inside a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you have two adjacent JSX elements ( and ) that are not wrapped in a single parent element. In React, you can only return a single parent element from a component.

To fix this issue, you can wrap both elements in a single parent  or another container element.